# Rendering difference in custom control

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I'm currently facing problems rendering an **sap.suite.ui.microchart.InteractiveDonutChart**. I want to render it in a custom control. When I try to render a simple control like **sap.m.Text**, it works just fine. However, it doesn't with the donut chart. Generating the donut chart like this in a controller works just fine, though. Any ideas as to why this doesn't work? It doesn't give me any errors...

### aggregations

```
aggregations: {
                content: {
                    type: "sap.ui.core.Control",
                    multiple: true,
                    singluarName: "content"
                }
            }
```

### renderer

```
        //start of content
        oRM.write("<div ");
        oRM.addClass("cardContent");
        oRM.writeClasses();
        oRM.write(">");
        oRM.renderControl(oControl.getChosenControl());
        oRM.renderControl(oControl.getChosenControl2());
        oRM.write("</div>"); // close div 3
        //end of content
```

### functions

```
getChosenControl: function() {
        var flexBox = new sap.m.FlexBox({
            width: "90%",
            alignItems: "Center"
        });

        var textField = new sap.m.Text({
            text: "Dynamically created textfield"
        });

        flexBox.addItem(textField);
        return flexBox;
    },

    getChosenControl2: function() {

        var flexBox = new sap.m.FlexBox({
            width: "90%",
            alignItems: "Center"
        });

        var donutChart = new sap.suite.ui.microchart.InteractiveDonutChart();

        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            var segment = new sap.suite.ui.microchart.InteractiveDonutChartSegment();
            segment.setLabel("Parter");
            segment.setValue(50);
            segment.setDisplayedValue("50 %");

            donutChart.addSegment(segment);
        }


        flexBox.addItem(donutChart);
        return flexBox;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found a solution myself. I first added it to my aggregation 'content' with the 'AddContent' method. The next step is to get the content with the 'getContent' method. The last step is to render the returned content.

```
            //start of content
                oRM.write("<div ");
                oRM.addClass("cardContent");
                oRM.writeClasses();
                oRM.write(">");

                //add content
                oControl.addContent(oControl.getChosenControl2());

                //get content
                var items = oControl.getContent();

                //render items      
                for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                    oRM.renderControl(oControl.getContent()[i]);
                }

                oRM.write("</div>"); // close div 3
                //end of content
```

Comment: If anyone else finds a shorter or better solution, please let me know!